# Preventing delete where 1 using typeof in node-mysql

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I am using node-mysql.

I have noticed that when I pass in `1` to a delete query, my whole table gets dropped. This makes sense with my syntax, however I want to protect against accidental drops.

Right now, I'm prevent this by making sure you pass in a object to the query using `typeof`. Is this reliable?

```
exports.destroy = function (sel, next) {
  if (typeof sel !== 'object') {
    //it defaults to id if you don't sepcify and object.
    sel = {'id' : sel};
  }
  db.query('DELETE FROM users WHERE ?', sel, next);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's not table being dropped, but all rows being deleted. Secondly, use “[prepared statements](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values)”.

Following is somewhat bloated, but the main idea is using function similar to `removeQuery`. If you need condition different from equality, you can pass it to modified version as a string like `post_rating < ?` (you and not user, resulting sql should be someting like `DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_rating < ?;`).

**Though, validation, schemas and similar stuff should go to [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) of some kind.**

```js
var util = require('util');

var db = {
  query: function (sql, params, callback) {
    console.log('executing sql `%s` with params `%j`', sql, params);
    callback();
  }
};

function removeQuery(db, table, whereField, type) {
  var sql = util.format('DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = ?;', table, whereField);
  var fn  = db.query.bind(db, sql);

  return function (value, callback) {
    callback = callback || function () {};
    if (typeof value != type) {
      var message = util.format('Invalid type of `%s` field: should be `%s`; got `%s`',
                                whereField, type, typeof value);
      var err = new Error(message);
      console.error(err);
      return process.nextTick(callback.bind(null, err));
    }

    fn([value], callback);
  };
}

exports.removeUserByUsername = removeQuery(db, 'users', 'username', 'string');
exports.removePostByUserId   = removeQuery(db, 'posts', 'user_id', 'number');

[42, 'tony', undefined].forEach(function (val) {
  exports.removeUserByUsername(val);
  exports.removePostByUserId(val);
});
```